# Does BinaryOp and UnaryOp exist?

Tags: c++, binary, include

Was given this piece of code to implement in my c++ header, unfortunately BinaryOp and UnaryOp are read as syntax errors, is there a #include for these or is it made up?

Here is code for reference:

```
UnaryOp Parser::tokenToUnaryOperator(Token t)
 {
   static map<Token, UnaryOp> transMap
   {
     {Token::MINUS, UnaryOp::MINUS},
     {Token::NOT, UnaryOp::NOT}
   };
   map<Token, UnaryOp>::iterator it = transMap.find(t);
   if (it == transMap.end())
     throw "Exception: this token is not a unary operator.";
     return it->second;
}
```

Comment: Well, they are not standard types.  They are probably part of the code base you are using.

Comment: Not part of the standard C++ language. And here is a reference site where you can look-up such information: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp

Comment: good to know, thanks